# PHP Create dir fails

Tags: php, mkdir

i have ran into bit of a problem, i want to create a temp dir for some image uploads.

here is what i have:

if i run `root@dev:/var/www/media# tree draft/` it returns
`draft/ [error opening dir]`
the dir is not there (and thats correct), so i want php to create the dir
then i use this:

```
if(!is_dir(MEDIA_PATH . "draft")){
  create_dir(MEDIA_PATH . "draft");
}
if(!is_dir(MEDIA_PATH . "draft/product")){
  create_dir(MEDIA_PATH . "draft/product");
}
if(!is_dir(MEDIA_PATH . "draft/product/" . $temp_id)){
  create_dir(MEDIA_PATH . "draft/product/" . $temp_id);
}
function create_dir($file){
    echo "create_dir: {$file}" . PHP_EOL;
    $dir = dirname($file);
    if(!is_dir($dir)){
        umask(0000);
        if(false === mkdir($dir, 0777, true) && !is_dir($dir)){
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf("Unable to create the directory (%s).", $dir));
        }
        umask(0022);
    }elseif(!is_writable($dir)){
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf("Unable to write in the directory (%s).", $dir));
    }
}
```

(https://gist.github.com/keja/840291d1abb7355f07aa)

that results in

```
create_dir: /var/www/media/draft
create_dir: /var/www/media/draft/product
create_dir: /var/www/media/draft/product/56d038fe-0906-9442-c2d7-ab2b841467af
```

then if i run the tree command again

```
root@dev:/var/www/media# tree draft/
draft/
└── product
```

for some reason it will not create the last dir, any ideas?
the /var/www/media is a NFS mount, but should not have anything todo with the problem i guess.

## EDIT: Problem is solved.

the solution was to remove the `$dir = dirname($filename);` and change the `$file` param to `$dir` instead.

```
function create_dir($dir){
    if(!is_dir($dir)){
        umask(0000);
        if(false === mkdir($dir, 0777, true) && !is_dir($dir)){
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf("Unable to create the directory (%s).", $dir));
        }
        umask(0022);
    }elseif(!is_writable($dir)){
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf("Unable to write in the directory (%s).", $dir));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm are this might sound daft but have you checked that you have correct permissions in that folder?

Comment: it can create the draft folder and the product folder within draft, so i dont think its problem with the permissions

Comment: Twenty years ago (or even more) I would say the name of the innermost sub-directory is too long. We are in 2015 now and I hope this is not the reason. However it doesn't hurt to check if you can create it using the `mkdir` shell command.

Comment: i can create it in the shell (as root), but all the other folders php creates are: `drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 24 11:21 product`
so it should have all access to create new level folder.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i have found the problem, it was the dirname function that caused the problem.